# Shared User Defaults via App Groups in iOS 11 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults, ios11, ios-app-group

Did anyone face an issue with Shared User Defaults via App Groups on iOS 11? I am saving a value in one of the extensions but I am not able to fetch same value via another extension.

In the first extension :

```swift
let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: Constants.commonSuite)
defaults.set("Sample", forKey: "SampleKey")
defaults.synchronize()
```

In the second extension :

```swift
let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: Constants.commonSuite)
let sampleString = defaults.object(forKey: "SampleKey")
print(sampleString)
```

Interestingly this thing works fine on iOS 10. Breaks on iOS 11

Comment: Hey @mayuur, I'm facing the exact same issue and haven't been able to find a solution for this. I've enabled App groups in my action extension as well as my host app. I'm still getting a standard error in console and i'm unable to access the values. Even trying to access the keys return a nil.

Comment: I don't know if you got a solution, but this answer and its comments seem to have had success by making a new shared container. Admittedly it relates to pre-iOS11 but might be worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Suitename needs to be the same value as your app group name, not some arbitrary value.

Hope that helps!